# RecyclerView ItemTouchHelper swipe action is not working in Fragment Class

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

[image]I have a recyclerview inside one of a fragment class under `FragmentViewPagerAdapter`. Here at `Recyclerview` I implement `ItemTouchHelper` for a swipe which is not happening. Does anyone have come across this issue.

Can't use itemtouchhelper swipe feature because of viewpageradapter swipe action.

```
public SwipeHelper(ListAdapter adapter, Context context) {
    super(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT);
    this.adapter = adapter;
    this.context = context;
}

public SwipeHelper(int dragDirs, int swipeDirs) {
    super(dragDirs, swipeDirs);
}

@Override
public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "swipe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
    ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback = new SwipeHelper(adapter,getActivity());
    ItemTouchHelper helper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
    helper.attachToRecyclerView(leadRV);
```

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: The `ViewPager` is consuming the horizontal swipes. How do you mean to differentiate whether a swipe is supposed to affect a `RecyclerView` item, or move the `ViewPager`?

Comment: Where is code ? What you have tried so far ?

Comment: @Mike M. Yes swipe affecting viewpager and i can't implement recyclerview itemtouchhelper swipe feature.

Comment: You can override onTouchEvent() in the ViewPager and return false- this shouls let the touches to get to the RecyclerVIew

Comment: @X3Btel can you please support showing an example.

Answer (score 0):

Of-course you can implement Item Touch Helper easily but you have to keep some points in your mind. if you are using on attach listener with reinterview to implement Item touch listener then please don't implement Item Touch Helper in Bind view holder and if you have already declared touch in on bind view holder or in view holder then don't implement it inside on attach listener. 
Try it and still you are getting error then update your code here.

Comment: I have added a code so can u help me suggesting where should i go for a change in my code.